# Plotly (offline) for Python click event

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, scatter

Is it possible to add click events to a Plotly scatter plot (offline mode in Python)?

As an example, I want to change the shape of a set of scatter points upon being clicked.

**What I tried so far**

My understanding from reading other questions from the site (with no clear answer) is that I may have to produce the html and then edit it after the fact by putting in javascript code? So I could write a javascript function, save it off to my_js.js and then link to it from the html?

Answer (score 3):

I've been doing some work with offline plots in plotly and had the same challenge.

Here's a kludge I've come up with which my prove as inspiration for others.

Some limitations:

- Assumes that you have the offline output in a single html file, for a single plot.
- Assumes that your on events are named the same as the event handlers.
- Requires Beautiful Soup 4.
- Assumes you've got lxml installed.
- Developed with Plotly 2.2.2

Code Snippet:

```
import bs4

def add_custom_plotly_events(
    filename, 
    events = {
        "plotly_click": "function plotly_click(data) { console.log(data); }",
        "plotly_hover": "function plotly_hover(data) { console.log(data); }"
    },
    prettify_html = True
):

    # what the value we're looking for the javascript
    find_string = "Plotly.newPlot"

    # stop if we find this value
    stop_string = "then(function(myPlot)"

    def locate_newplot_script_tag(soup):    
        scripts = soup.find_all('script')
        script_tag = soup.find_all(string=re.compile(find_string))

        if len(script_tag) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Couldn't locate the newPlot javascript in {}".format(filename))
        elif len(script_tag) > 1:
            raise ValueError("Located multiple newPlot javascript in {}".format(filename))

        if script_tag[0].find(stop_string) > -1:
            raise ValueError("Already updated javascript, it contains:", stop_string)

        return script_tag[0]

    def split_javascript_lines(new_plot_script_tag):
        return new_plot_script_tag.string.split(";")

    def find_newplot_creation_line(javascript_lines):
        for index, line in enumerate(javascript_lines):
            if line.find(find_string) > -1:
                return index, line
        raise ValueError("Missing new plot creation in javascript, couldn't find:", find_string)

    def join_javascript_lines(javascript_lines):
        # join the lines with javascript line terminator ;    
        return ";".join(javascript_lines)

    def register_on_events(events):
        on_events_registration = []
        for function_name in events:
            on_events_registration.append("myPlot.on('{}', {})".format(
                function_name, function_name
            ))
        return on_events_registration

    # load the file
    with open(filename) as inf:
        txt = inf.read()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt, "lxml")

    new_plot_script_tag = locate_newplot_script_tag(soup)

    javascript_lines = split_javascript_lines(new_plot_script_tag)

    line_index, line_text = find_newplot_creation_line(javascript_lines)    

    on_events_registration = register_on_events(events)

    # replace whitespace characters with actual whitespace
    # using + to concat the strings as {} in format
    # causes fun times with {} as the brackets in js
    # could possibly overcome this with in ES6 arrows and such
    line_text = line_text + ".then(function(myPlot) { " + join_javascript_lines(on_events_registration) +"  })".replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')

    # now add the function bodies we've register in the on handles
    for function_name in events:
        javascript_lines.append(events[function_name])

    # update the specific line
    javascript_lines[line_index] = line_text

    # update the text of the script tag
    new_plot_script_tag.string.replace_with(join_javascript_lines(javascript_lines))

    # save the file again
    with open(filename, "w") as outf:
        # tbh the pretty out is still ugly af
        if prettify_html:
            for line in soup.prettify(formatter = None):
                outf.write(str(line))
        else:
            outf.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: How do you use this function? If you could show a (basic) example, that would be great!

Comment: As part of report generation process I had some plotly scatter plots (aggregations of state ,and below state aggregations of areas) that were generated. I needed them to be offline plots due to firewall fun times.
I used the onclick to move between the State level aggregation to drill down into the area level aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Click events in python offline mode?](https://community.plot.ly/t/click-events-in-python-offline-mode/298/3) on Plotly's [community site](https://community.plot.ly/) this is not supported, at least as of December 2015.

That post does contain some hints as to how to implement this functionality yourself, if you're feeling adventurous.